# evaluation of infinite series expansion

Tags: sequences-and-series

> $(1)$ How can i find $\displaystyle \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}b_{n}x^n,$ If

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}b_{n}x^n=\bigg(\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}x^{n}\bigg)^2$$

> $(2)$ How can i find $\displaystyle \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}c_{n}x^n,$ If

$$\bigg(\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}c_{n}x^n\bigg)\cdot \bigg(\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}x^{n}\bigg)=1$$

What i try::

For $(1)$

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}b_{n}x^n=\frac{x^2}{(1-x)^2}=\frac{(x^2-2x+1)+2x-2+1}{(1-x)^2}$$

$$=1-\frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$

I did not understand how can i solve further. Help me please

For $(2)$

$$\bigg(\frac{1}{1-x}\bigg)\cdot \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}c_{n}x^n=1$$

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}c_{n}x^n=1-x$$

Help me please, Thanks

Comment: Do you know that for $|x|<1$, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac1{1-x}$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^n=\frac1{(1-x)^2}$?

Comment: Maybe learn how to multiply series (e.g. find the Cauchy product)  as well, in case that's required in your exams etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT:**

For $|x|<1$, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac1{1-x}$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^{n-1}=\frac1{(1-x)^2}$.

Comment: Thanks Mark Viola. You mean $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}nx^{n-1}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$

Comment: @jacky You're welcome. My pleasure.  And you're correct; I've edited.

Comment: (+1) easy peasy

Answer (score 2):

Recall Cauchy's formula for product os power series:

$$
\Big(\sum_{n\geq0}a_nz^n\Big)\Big(\sum_{n\geq0}b_nx^n\Big)=\sum_{n\geq0}c_nz^n
$$
where $c_n=a_nb_0+a_{n-1}b_1+\ldots a_0b_n=\sum^n_{k=0}a_{n-k}b_k$.

In (1) for instcance, you have $a_n=b_n=1$ for all $n\geq0$ and so $c_n=n+1$, that is
$$
\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\Big(\sum^\infty_{n=0}x^n\Big)^2=\sum^\infty_{n=0}(n+1)x^n$$

For (2) you have,

$$\bigg(\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}c_{n}x^n\bigg)\cdot \bigg(\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}x^{n}\bigg)=\sum_{n\geq0}d_nx^n=1$$

where $d_n=c_0+c_1+\ldots c_n$. Putting things together, you get

$$
c_0 =1,
$$
and
$$
c_0+c_1+\ldots +c_n=0, \quad n\geq1
$$
Thus,  $c_0=1$, $c_1=-1$, and $c_n=0$ for $n\geq2$. This is not surprising since $$
(1-x)\sum_{n\geq0}x^n=(1-x)\frac{1}{1-x}=1
$$
but, the strategy can be applied to more general problems some of which a appear in the analytical solutions to certain linear differential equations.